# Powershell for Linux via PHP exec

Tags: php, linux, powershell, exec

OS: Debian 8.1
PHP Version 7.0.23-1~dotdeb+8.1
nginx/1.12.1

$PSVersionTable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.0.0-beta
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    v6.0.0-beta.7
OS                             Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u3 (2017-08-15)
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

The following example command worked well until i updated the system via apt-get:

```
exec("powershell -help", $out));
```

after the update, the command above returns an empty string.
I also tried to debug this command:

```
exec("powershell -help 2>&1", $out);
var_dump($out);

array(7) { [0]=> string(63) "FailFast: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(66) " at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)" [3]=> string(66) " at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)" [4]=> string(88) " at Microsoft.PowerShell.UnmanagedPSEntry.Start(System.String, System.String[], Int32)" [5]=> string(63) " at Microsoft.PowerShell.ManagedPSEntry.Main(System.String[])" [6]=> string(7) "Aborted" }

exec("strace -v powershell -help 2>&1", $out);
var_dump($out);
```

I just see that many files and directories are missing but i don't know why or how to fix it.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy powershell` returns?

Comment: powershell:
  Installed:           6.0.0-beta.7-1ubuntu1.14.04.1
  Installation candidate: 6.0.0-beta.7-1ubuntu1.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 6.0.0-beta.7-1ubuntu1.14.04.1 0
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/14.04/prod/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6.0.0-beta.6-1ubuntu1.14.04.1 0
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/14.04/prod/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     6.0.0-beta.5-1ubuntu1.14.04.1 0
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/14.04/prod/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
[...]

Comment: If you run `powershell -help` in terminal it works?

Comment: yes if i run it from commandline everything works like expected.

Comment: "echo exec("pwd");" also works. Only the combination of exec and powershell leads to the described error.